# TMOUT using SFTP

Tags: unix, timeout, solaris

regarding the variable TMOUT. I have used

```
export TMOUT=3600
```

but my SSH terminal still gets time out even less than 10minutes without keyboard activity. How can I change this TMOUT value to 3600?

Also, if I use sftp to transfer a very large local file (in GB) to the server, will I get timed out as well?

thanks

Comment: TMOUT is normally declared as a read-only variable, so that you cannot override or overwite it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be the solution to your problem :

http://www.daveperrett.com/articles/2006/08/17/stop-ssh-and-sftp-timeout/

A transfer won't timeout, it's activity.